# Recommend way to handle unit conversion

Tags: python, pyqt4, data-conversion

I'm making a GUI with pyqt4 and python. Right now I have a QLineEdit and QComboBox, where the QLineEdit displays the values and the QComboBox can be used to change units. I'm using signals and slots to handle real time unit/value feedback for the user but I'm having problems understanding how to programmatically work with the values as I need them all to be in standard units. Here's what I've got so far, the combo_box_line_edit_list is a list of list where I wrap the combo box and line list together

```
class UnitConverterSignaler(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, combo_box_line_edit_list):
        super(QtCore.QObject, self).__init__()
        self.combo_box_line_edit_list = combo_box_line_edit_list

        self.combo_box_list = [line_edit_combo_box[0] for line_edit_combo_box in combo_box_line_edit_list]

        for combo_box, line_edit in self.combo_box_line_edit_list:
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(line_edit.convert_units)
            line_edit.store_unit_state(combo_box.currentText())
            line_edit.standard_unit = combo_box.itemText(1)


    def convert_to_standard(self):
        for combo_box in self.combo_box_list:
            combo_box.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def convert_to_international(self):
        for combo_box in self.combo_box_list:
            combo_box.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def toggle_unit_conversion(self, hold_line_values_steady):
        for combo_box in self.combo_box_list:
            if hold_line_values_steady:
                combo_box.do_not_convert_units_on_change()
            else:
                combo_box.convert_units_on_change()

    def convert_units_on_change(self):
        """
        Changes the value of the line edit each time the combo box is changed
        """
        for combo_box, line_edit in self.combo_box_line_edit_list:
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(line_edit.convert_units)
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged['QString'].disconnect(line_edit.store_unit_state)

    def do_not_convert_units_on_change(self):
        """
        Holds the line edit value constant in spite of combo box changes
        """
        for combo_box, line_edit in self.combo_box_line_edit_list:
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged['QString'].disconnect(line_edit.convert_units)
            combo_box.currentIndexChanged['QString'].connect(line_edit.store_unit_state)
```

Instantiated & used in another class

```
self.lockCellCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.unit_converter_signaler.toggle_unit_conversion)
self.internationalPushButton.clicked.connect(self.unit_converter_signaler.convert_to_international)
self.standardPushButton.clicked.connect(self.unit_converter_signaler.convert_to_standard)
```

I've also monkey patched the QLineEdit instead of subclassing so I can make quick changes with QtDesigner.

```
# monkey patch slot onto line_edit
def convert_units(line_edit, end_unit):
    converted_unit_value = line_edit.unit_registry.convert(float(line_edit.text()), line_edit.stored_unit_state, str(end_unit))
    line_edit.setText(str(converted_unit_value))
    line_edit.stored_unit_state = str(end_unit)

# monkey patch slot onto line_edit
def store_unit_state(line_edit, unit):
    line_edit.stored_unit_state = str(unit)
```

Would the most generalized way to get the standard units out in my main program be the creation of a signal for each combo box/line edit in the UnitConverter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood so far: you have many combo-box/line-edit pairs and the entered values should always be converted to standard units (e.g. displayed on a third QLabel or whatever).

> Would the most generalized way to get the standard units out in my main program be the creation of a signal for each combo box/line edit in the UnitConverter?

No, you don't have to. A *slot* in python (or especially in pyqt) can be any callable object. A callable object is an object with method `__call__(self)` implemented.
Therefore I would suggest you to create a class which takes the related object(s) as parameter(s) in the contructor and changes them in `__call__(self)`. Something like this:

```
class ConverterSignal:
    def __init__(whatever_you_want_to_refer_to):
        self.whatever_you_want_to_refer_to = whatever_you_want_to_refer_to

    def __call(self)__:
        """ Here you can refer to whatever_you_want_to_refer_to and do whatever you want with it """
```

The connection is done as following (for the combo box as an example):

```
self.connect(combo_box, QtCore.SIGNAL('activated(int)'), ConverterSignal(whatever_you_want_to_refer_to))
```

Here an instance of the class `ConverterSignal` is created and will be called if the corresponding signal is emitted.

Comment: This is where I ended up with my current understanding. I'm looking into using delegates or proxy models in the future. Sorry to take so long to accept the answer